# Laravel - where to store site config data

Tags: laravel

I have got option to disable/enable registration of users. Where should i store this data? What is the best practise?

I think, that store this little data in DB is not good solution.

Comment: General rule of thumb: Is it changeable through some sort of user interface? -> DB. Otherwise config/environment file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope you know the concept of Environment Variables

In Laravel its stored in .env.php file

```
<?php

return [
    'user_registration'  => 'enable/disable'
];

?>
```

You can retrieve the value as

```
$_ENV['user_registration']
```

And manipulate the function accordingly. For ex. if enable then show the form else hide it from Views

Documentation:

> http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: That is nice, is there any function to set the config variable, or smt? Because this option will be changeable in administration by normal user.

Comment: make this file writable and use file manipulation to do it. Its an array so manipulating is easy.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, you can just add this line inside your registration function

```
return redirect()->back();
```

So, that user will not be able to see registration page. and when you want to enable it again, you can comment the above line and you're good to go.

Comment: It's not about users being active. It's about disabling registration of new users altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would want to flip the switch on registration of users on an admin panel. I.e, create a user interface and set a value in a table somewhere in a far away database.

The easiest way however, is simply to create a config file.

My laravel deployments come with a 'website' config, where i place all the website's related configuration values in it.

**Steps:**

1. Create a configuration file: `config/website.php`
2. In the `website.php` file:

   `return [
       'registration' => true
   ];`
3. In your controllers, simply add `if(\Config::get('website.registration'))` to check whether user registration is on/off.

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration

Comment: Is there any function, which will edit the file and replace "true" for some variable? I will be using this in administration, i mean, that user will be able to change this option in admin, my clients will not have access to edit php files.

Comment: Then you'll have to make your own. I.e setup your configuration table in your database, and build the MVC for it